# mantle - How to write value transformer for a dictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, github-mantle

I have this response from an API and trying to find ways to map this to an NSDictionary using a Mantle value transformer.

```
 {
   "baggage": {
    "BAG10": "3.5",
    "BAG15": "3.5",
    "BAG20": "3.5",
    "BAG30": "3.5",
    "BAG40": "3.5"
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: map to NSDictionary means..? how ur output will be ?

Comment: The output will be a NSDictionary which holds the key and value pairs ie.
 - <NSString *, NSNumber *>

Comment: u want to access  "baggage".

Comment: yes. I want to know how to write a value transformer for the property "baggage", which is defined as a dictionary

Comment: check it will print what are the values inside **baggage**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By the looks of it, we don't need to write any transformers for this property. Mantle handles by itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can use NSJSONSerialization passing in the server response as NSData

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]
```